# Há como desabilitar o "Debugger Exception Notification" do Delphi?

Tags: delphi, exceção, debug

Gostaria de desabilitar a função do qual o debugger me notifica uma Exceção em um trecho de código.

## Exemplo:

```delphi
try
   Text := CurrToStrF('Erro', ffNumber, 2);
except
   Text := '0,00';
end;
```

Durante a depuração do código acima em algumas ocasiões é lançado a exceção e a depuração pausa exibindo uma mensagem na tela.

Contudo, como eu sei que ele irá lançar a exceção, eu queria que o delphi ignorasse as exceções **somente** nessa parte.

Tem alguma diretiva (ou outro meio) que avisasse o depurador pra não parar?

Estou utilizando o Delphi 2009

Comment: Qual a versão do `delphi` que estás utilizando?

Comment: A versão usada é o Delphi 2009

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possivel sim.

Coloque um `Breakpoint` no ponto a partir do qual você não quer que o depurador notifique sobre novas exceções.

Clique com o botão direito nele e selecione `Breakpoint properties` clique em `Advanced` desmarque `Break` e marque `Ignore subsequent exceptions`.

Depois coloque um `Breakpoint` no ponto que deseja que o depurador volte a notificar as exceções.

Clique com o botão direito nele e selecione `Breakpoint properties` clique em `Advanced` desmarque `Break` e marque `Handle subsequent exceptions`.

Depois disso quando debugar o depurador não irá notificar sobre qualquer exceção que ocorra nesse trecho.

Porem quando você fechar o projeto os `Breakpoints` vão ser perdidos, para evitar isso você deve habilitar o auto salvamento da área de trabalho do projeto.

Para fazer isso você deve ir até `Tools->Options` em `Environment options` lá procure por `Auto save` e marque `Project desktop` ou `Project workspace`.

Answer (score 4):

## Resposta:

Sim, há como desabilita-lo.

## Explicação:

**Delphi 7** - No menu superior, clique em `Tools`-`Debugger Options` abrirá uma janela, navegue até a aba `Language Exceptions` e você verá uma checkbox dizendo `[ ] Stop on delphi exceptions` marque-a, pronto.

**Delphi XE5** - No menu superior, clique em `Tools`-`Options` abrirá uma janela, navegue na lista que tem na esquerda, lá embaixo no final você vai encontrar `Debugger Options` clique na flechinha pra abrir ele aí você vai encontrar `Language Exceptions`, ai você vai ter a checkbox lá embaixo escrito `Notify on language exceptions`, é só desmarcar e pronto.

**Obs:** Eu deduzi que você utiliza a versão `7` ou a `XE5` do delphi, pois são as mais utilizadas atualmente, se a versão do seu delphi não for a `7` nem a `XE5`, me avise pois encontrarei a solução para a sua versão editando esta resposta.

Comment: +1. No entanto seria bom mesmo se ele falasse a versão, estou usando o 2006 e na minha IDE o nome é "Notify on language exceptions". Mas só muda isso mesmo, acho que ele não vai ter problemas.

Comment: Na verdade não quero que todas as exceptions sejam ignoradas, nem que seja ignorado todos as exceções ( marcando o checkbox na mensagem lançada pelo depurador ) somente desejo que naquele pedaço de codigo o depurador não pare.